# Function info tooltip in notebook misaligned in Mathematica 11.2

Tags: front-end

When typing out a function in the first cell of a notebook, the info tooltip seems to be misaligned, appearing above the function and cutting into the window frame. This behavior, however, does not occur when typing out a function in the second or subsequent cells.

Moreover, I do not believe this occurred under < 11.2. Is this a new bug, or am I the only one experiencing such a phenomenon.

EDIT:

I believe this only happens if you change the font to Courier, using

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, StyleHints -> {"CodeFont" -> "Courier"}]
```

EDIT 2: Changing the magnification to anything beyond `1.06036` (can be precisely set in options inspector) fixes the issue. I'm tempted to believe the root cause is due to some difference in expected font size between Consolas and Source Code Pro (the new font used in 11+). In either case is this an acceptable work around and doesn't lead to too bad a deviation.

[image]

Comment: i can't reproduce the bug on mathematica 11.2 & windows 10.

Comment: @Alucard Even when you set the stylehint to Courier?

Comment: no bug in both cases.

Comment: Can't reproduce with M11.2 on macOS 10.13 (with Courier or otherwise)

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions (see tag description).

Comment: Better fix than zoom is to change the CellMargins for the Input cell. Just bumping the top margin by 1px for input cells is sufficient to fix the issue. If you want you can then decrease the bottom margin for output cells by 1px to preserve the rest. Based on this I'm pretty sure this comes down to a <= 10.9 specific issue in something about the window chrome being different.